# GDI+ FillClosedCurve giving strange loop effect?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

I'm using the GDI+ function FillClosedCurve (in C# if that matters), to draw a series of points as a nice "rounded" curve area. The problem is that it appears to be adding a strange "loop" shape to one corner of the resulting shape. The screenshot shows this little extra loop at the top right corner of my red coloured area -
[image: My curve screenshot]

the code is

```
g.FillClosedCurve(shapeBrush, shapePoints.ToArray(), FillMode.Winding, 0.4f);
g.DrawPolygon(blackPen, shapePoints.ToArray());
```

I added a black border with the DrawPolygon function so you can see where my coordinates are.

Can anyone tell me why I get that weird loop shape at the top right corner ??
Thank you.

Comment: Are you specifying the top right point more than once in your array?..if so then you shouldn't....because it "closes" it for you.

Comment: Colin - yes your right, I was doing that ! The coordinates are calculated, it wasn't the closing point but a point somewhere in the middle of the list was duplicated. I remove the duplicate & the curve renders correctly. Thank you. If you want to post as an answer, I'll award you the points ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by you specifying the same point more than once in the array i.e. as the first and last point.

`FillClosedCurve` "closes" the path for you....so there is no need...in fact it's incorrect to specify the point twice....as it will then try and close the path from a point back to the point at the same position....which causes the artifact.

Here's a little example to demonstrate the difference:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    PointF[] arrayDuplicatedPointAtStartAndEnd =
    {
        new PointF(20.0F, 20.0F),
        new PointF(150.0F, 50.0F),
        new PointF(150.0F, 150.0F),
        new PointF(20.0F, 20.0F),
    };

    PointF[] arrayWithoutPointOverlap =
    {
        new PointF(20.0F, 20.0F),
        new PointF(150.0F, 50.0F),
        new PointF(150.0F, 150.0F)
    };

    float tension = 0.4F;

    using (SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillClosedCurve(redBrush, arrayDuplicatedPointAtStartAndEnd, FillMode.Winding, tension);
    }

    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(110.0f, 0.0f, MatrixOrder.Prepend);

    using (SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillClosedCurve(blueBrush, arrayWithoutPointOverlap, FillMode.Winding, tension);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Colin, I've been staring at the code for a while, it just didn't make sense to me.